# Restart command for Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

This code:

```
await Bot.close()
```

is used to logout the Bot.
The problem is that i want write a restart command, like this:

```
@Bot.command()
async def OFF(ctx, seconds:float):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = Embed(title = "OFF", description = f"{ctx.message.author.mention} turned off me for {round(seconds)} seconds", color = Color.red())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    await Bot.close()
    await sleep(seconds)
    await Bot.login(token)
    embed = Embed(title = "Turned on", description = f"I came back after {round(seconds)}", color = Color.green())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

The problem is that when the Bot closes, the shell must be restarted, otherwise the program won't keep running after {seconds}sec.

How could i create a command which restarts the Bot?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `await sleep()` is outdated, you rather use `asyncio.sleep()`. Have you looked at other posts that also deal with restarting a bot? There are tons of examples on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, i looked to other posts, no-one of them answered my question.

Comment: (@Dominik, i did "from time import sleep" at the beginning of te program)

Answer (score 2):

So you should be able to just disconnect and then reconnect without the terminal closing.

Notice I'm using `.connect()` instead of `.login()` as when you close the connection you're not actually logging out of discord.

Edit: I hadn't noticed but Dominik mentioned the thats sleep is not asynchronous and so you can either make it asynchronous (although its unnecessary), by importing asyncio and using `await asyncio.sleep(seconds)` or just use the time.sleep function as you were but without the await.

```py
@Bot.command()
async def OFF(ctx, seconds:float):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = Embed(title = "OFF", description = f"{ctx.message.author.mention} turned off me for {round(seconds)} seconds", color = Color.red())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    await Bot.close()
    sleep(seconds)
    await Bot.connect()
    embed = Embed(title = "Turned on", description = f"I came back after {round(seconds)}", color = Color.green())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: This didn't work. I had the same problem as before, after the Bot.close() call the shell ended.

Comment: Try running the script in cmd with `python bot_file.py`. And tell me if there are any errors raised when using the command.

Comment: there's no error raised, but after Bot.close() call the .exe file simply closes

Answer (score 0):

You can completely restart you bot by using the [`os.execv()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execv).

> "[...] execute[s] a new program, replacing the current process; [it does] not return"

---

The implementation would be

```py
os.execv("path-to-python-bin", ["python"] + ["absolute-path-to-bot-main-file"])
```

for example

```py
os.execv("/usr/local/bin/python3.8", ["python"] + ["/home/user/test/bot.py"])
```

---

Your command could be implemented like this

```py
@Bot.command()
async def OFF(ctx, seconds:float):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = Embed(title = "OFF", description = f"{ctx.message.author.mention} turned off me for {round(seconds)} seconds", color = Color.red())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    os.execv("path-to-python-bin", ["python"] + ["absolute-path-to-bot-main-file"])
```

Discord.py will handle all logouts, and re-logins for you. No need to call the functions seperately.

Comment: This is not pratical at all, it restarts the entire script, instead of the bot, and sacrifices the efficiency because the bot has to re-log in. I'd suggest use a discord.py solution.

Comment: This is a bad idea, `os.exec*` will eat your memory up by not letting old processes die. OP should run the bot in a process manager and let it handle the bot restart.

Comment: @Judev1, I know, do you have any suggestion for a Discord.py solution?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys
def restart_bot(): 
  os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

@bot.command(name= 'restart')
async def restart(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Restarting bot...")
  restart_bot()
```

This will work perfect . Your code doesnt works because once bot is stops by using bot.close it cant be turned on automatically

Comment: @Judev1 this goes for your command . atleast it doesnt works for me